# Why is my custom rake task in lib/tasks not discovered in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Build-in rake tasks work fine, but my new custom one, in Project/lib/tasks/payments.rb doesn't get loaded:

```
namespace :payments  do
  desc "Tally payments at the end of the month"
  task :compute => :environment do
    BillingPeriod.compute_new_period
  end
end

$ rake payments:compute
(in /Users/rob/Code/Apps/skyfarm)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'payments:compute'
```

It works fine if I load the file application.rb:

```
require 'lib/tasks/payments.rb'
```

...but it breaks other things:

```
$ rails s
./lib/tasks/payments.rb:1: undefined method `namespace' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: In case anybody ends up here who is *not* using Rails: put your `.rake` files in a directory called `rakelib`.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Change the file extension from `.rb` to `.rake`.

Comment: If this does not help, there I found a solution: http://blog.nathanhumbert.com/2010/02/rails-3-loading-rake-tasks-from-gem.html

Answer (score 33):

In this specific case, not having a `.rake` extension caused the error. However, I had the same issue with a Rails 4.2 app today, and it was because I did not have a `desc` for my rake task, so make sure if you're writing your own task (i.e. not generating one) that you add a `desc`.

For more information:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks

Comment: When I saw `However` in your answer, I already knew that your answer will solve my issue ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

As per the Rails guide [2.10 Custom Rake Tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks)

> Custom rake tasks have a .rake extension and are placed in Rails.root/lib/tasks.

But you have `.rb` extension.